# Naive Bayes Classification in R - from scratch

Tags: r, statistics, classification, bayesian, naivebayes

I wrote some code to make the **Naive Bayes Classifier** in R by hand using the `iris` dataset. I did the following:

- Divide the data into 3 classes
- Calculated mean and variance for each class
- Calculate probability using `dnorm`
- Multiply by the prior for each class

I am getting really *low probabilities* for each result. I am wondering whether the part for the **posterior function** is correct? Here is my code:

```
set.seed(1) #reproducibility
training_rows <- sort(c(sample(1:50, 40), sample(51:100, 40), sample(101:150, 40)))
training_x <- as.data.frame(iris[training_rows, 1:4])
training_y <- iris[training_rows, 5]

iris_nb <- function(x, trainx, trainy){
  train <- cbind(trainx, trainy)

  class_virginica <- train[which(train$trainy == 'virginica'),]
  class_setosa <- train[which(train$trainy == 'setosa'),]
  class_versicolor <- train[which(train$trainy == 'versicolor'),]

  posterior <- function(x, classtype){

    # Warning: bug here.
    p_Sepal.Length <- dnorm(x, mean(classtype[,1]), sd(classtype[,1]))
    p_Sepal.Width <- dnorm(x, mean(classtype[,2]), sd(classtype[,2]))
    p_Petal.Length <- dnorm(x, mean(classtype[,3]), sd(classtype[,3]))
    p_Petal.Width <- dnorm(x, mean(classtype[,4]), sd(classtype[,4]))

    vec <-  0.33* p_Sepal.Length * p_Sepal.Width * p_Petal.Length * p_Petal.Width #for each species
    return(vec)
}

  return(list(virginica = sum(posterior(x, class_virginica)), 
         setosa = sum(posterior(x, class_setosa)),
         versicolor = sum(posterior(x, class_versicolor))))
}
```

Here is the output:

```
test_case_1 <- as.matrix(iris[1, 1:4])
iris_nb(test_case_1, training_x, training_y)

## $virginica
## [1] 1.167108e-16

## $setosa
## [1] 2.136291e-54

## $versicolor
## [1] 1.636154e-32
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

1) The posterior you calculated is based on the fact that it's proportional the `prior * likelihood`. That's all well and good, but remember that Bayes Theorem says that the `posterior = prior * likelihood / marginal`. The marginal is very small, so dropping it from your calculation will make your posterior probability very small too (because you aren't dividing by it).

In general we don't care about these probabilities per se, we care about their relative size. So `virginica` appears to be many times more likely for this test case than the other species. So Naive Bayes would output `virginica`, the `argmax`.

2) Often times when working with products of probabilities (which is what your joint likelihood is) we use the log probabilities instead, since they are additive and won't cause numerical issues (which often occur when multiplying many small numbers together).

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR;

There is one bug in the code:

- You are giving `dnorm` a vector as the first argument, and it is returning a vector.  Give it a single value to have a single value returned.

### Explanation

Using your provided example consider the following:

```
trainx <- training_x; trainy <- training_y
train <- cbind(trainx, trainy)

class_setosa <- train[which(train$trainy == 'setosa'),]

mu <- mean(class_setosa[,1])
sigma <- sd(class_setosa[,1])

dnorm(test_case_1, mu, sigma)

##   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width
## 1     1.045569 0.0002481138 4.945912e-22 9.622888e-39
```

Notice that when given a vector, dnorm returns a vector.

The return value from `posterior` is immediately passed to `sum`, which hides the bug.

There are many ways to solve this issue, but in keeping with the intention of the original code the simplest solution is to index the vector of observations.

The solution is to index the vector.

```
dnorm(test_case_1[1], mu, sigma)

## [1] 1.045569
```

Note that dnorm does not return valid probabilities, which is evident in this case since the returned value is greater than 1.

### Final solution

The final solution looks like this

```
iris_nb <- function(x, trainx, trainy){
  train <- cbind(trainx, trainy)

  class_virginica <- train[which(train$trainy == 'virginica'),]
  class_setosa <- train[which(train$trainy == 'setosa'),]
  class_versicolor <- train[which(train$trainy == 'versicolor'),]

  posterior <- function(x, classtype){

    p_Sepal.Length <- dnorm(x[1], mean(classtype[,1]), sd(classtype[,1]))
    p_Sepal.Width  <- dnorm(x[2], mean(classtype[,2]), sd(classtype[,2]))
    p_Petal.Length <- dnorm(x[3], mean(classtype[,3]), sd(classtype[,3]))
    p_Petal.Width  <- dnorm(x[4], mean(classtype[,4]), sd(classtype[,4]))

    vec <-  0.33* p_Sepal.Length * p_Sepal.Width * p_Petal.Length * p_Petal.Width #for each species
    return(vec)
  }

  return(list(virginica = sum(posterior(x, class_virginica)), 
         setosa = sum(posterior(x, class_setosa)),
         versicolor = sum(posterior(x, class_versicolor))))
}
```

And with the same test case as your original question:

```
iris_nb(test_case_1, training_x, training_y)

## $virginica
## [1] 1.861745e-24

## $setosa
## [1] 2.82984

## $versicolor
## [1] 8.334494e-22
```

Note that the answer changed, now the argmax is setosa instead of virginica.
Also these are not valid posterior probabilities, but are proportional to the relevant probabilities so the argmax is still valid and that is what is used for classification with naive bayes.